# Can we say "4 peels of the banana"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> [peel](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/peel_2) 1- [uncountable, countable] the thick outer layer of some fruits
> and vegetables orange/lemon peel  (North American English also) an
> orange/a lemon peel
>
> 2- **peels** North American English(also peelings British and North
> American English) [plural] the skin of fruit or vegetables that has
> been removed

---

This is what I think

So if we refer to **the whole outer layer** of **a banana** in general then say “**a banana peel**”, for example, "**you need a banana peel to treat your acne**"

but if we already removed the skin of that banana, then we say “**the peels of the banana**”

[image]

For example, "**the above picture shows 4 peels of a banana**".

**Is that correct?**

Comment: No, if it's all in one piece, you'd still say "peel" (specifically here--"the banana peel").

Comment: On the other hand, it could be *four* ***peels*** [verb] of the banana. (The banana was peeled four times.)

Comment: IMO: You *can* say it, but it's unusual.

Comment: Not really, but there is a school boy joke whilst peeling a banana...one skin, two skin, three skin...

Comment: @Christopher, what does it mean?

Comment: @Tom, keep going, you will get it

Comment: @Tom ‘four skin’ has a homophone likely to make schoolboys snigger…  (See [here](https://youtu.be/QSWBX72rDe4) for a memorable example of that gag.)

Comment: This is how poetry got started

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would not use "peel" or "peelings" that way.

You could say.  "After you have peeled the potatoes, put the peels in the trash". I have an image of the skin of a fruit or vegetable that have been cut away with knife or special tool.

Although plural, and so "countable" we don't normally put a number on the word "peels" or "peelings". We don't say "the peels of (potato)", but we might say "the (potato) peels"

And in British English, always "peelings" for the above.

What your picture shows is a banana skin, or a banana peel, and there is only **one**.  If you pulled apart you would have 4 pieces of banana peel.

If you had two bananas, and ate them both, you would be left with two banana skins or peels.

Comment: Mind you, "The Four Peels of the Banana' would make a cool title for something :)

Comment: +1 for mentioning 'banana skin'. People sometimes slip on these and fall over.

Comment: However, you can say 'vegetable peel' (mass noun). It goes in the brown recycling bin in my house.

Comment: you could say `The Four Parts of the Banana Peel` or `Quarters`, if you specifically wanted to identify one part that way

Comment: @VaughnOhlman - Agreed. Sounds like a Sherlock Homes story.

Comment: Random observation, but don't banana peels usually come off in *five* pieces rather than four?  They are roughly pentagonal in cross-section.  I guess 2 of the sides might come off together sometimes, but to me that feels like the exception.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It depends on how ripe the banana is.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman also depends whether it's on the end of the bunch or in the middle - the flat sides are where it's against another banana, and they are in two staggered rows, so you get four flat and one curved in the middle but one less at the ends